# Per-user environment variables in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio, csproj

I want to set environment variables to my execution environment of a .NET app in Xamarin Studio on a per-user basis.  These environment variables may control things like logging or other debugging related configuration that should not be shared broadly.

Consider some trivial application:

```
using System;
public class TrivialApplication
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentValue("NAME"));
    }
}
```

I wish to be able to add an environment variable for `NAME` that appears when I run or debug the application.

I can add environment variables in Project Options > Run > General > Environment Variables, but these are saved in the `.csproj`, which is version controlled.  I would instead like these to go to a per-user configuration.

I naively tried to simply place the `EnvironmentVariables` lines into a `.csproj.user`:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <EnvironmentVariables>
   <EnvironmentVariables>
    <Variable name="NAME" value="value" />
   </EnvironmentVariables>
  </EnvironmentVariables>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

However either my `.csproj.user` is not read, or the environment variables are not applied.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Execution environment? What's that?

Comment: @LexLi: Please see my update if my original question was not appropriately clear.